# Django unsupported operand types

Tags: python, html, django

I'm getting an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'module' [09/Feb/2021 16:26:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 61800` while connecting client to the server. When I'm not connected all runs fine. Problem lies somewhere in my file views.py where i get error [image]

source code looks like this:
[image]

I've tried multiple of possibilities of concatenating two parts of the HttpResponse, always resulted in either problem with str and module or str and function. I know it just looks like a poor laziness but I swear I was trying to resolve the issue for the last 40 minutes and got a strong headache from that. So be kind, please. Thanks for any help, promise I'll respond to any feedback after I take a Aspirin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple use Double Quotes for the entire string, and single quotes for the link in the anchor tag, like this:

```py
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hey there partner! <a href='/rango/about/'>About</a>")

    return HttpResponse("Rango says here is the about page. <a href='/rango/'>Index</a>")
```

Comment: To elaborate, what was happening is that the single quotes in the anchor tag link was separating your string into two parts, which resulted in the expression `'string'/range`. That's what caused the error.

Comment: Thank you, expected something small of a issue like this.